# Django 3: Forgotten Password Reset: Is there a way to block password reset view to appear when ther user is logged in?

Tags: django, authentication, reset-password

I have implemented a built in Django password reset procedure using django.contrib.auth.views. It works, but there is a problem, when the user is logged in he/she still can type in password reset url and then reset the password. I would like to prevent password reset view to appear when the user is logged in. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**views.py:**

```
def password_reset(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        #Stuff
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
```

### OR

**shortcut way in class-base view**

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('password/reset/',PasswordResetView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True,),name='reset_password'),

# OR function base view..

path('password/reset/',PasswordResetView,{'redirect_authenticated_user': True},name='reset_password')
         
]
```

[Read the Docs..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

**settings.py:(Must)**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
```

Comment: The first option is ok, but I'm after the solution tweaking the PasswordResetView. Option with urls.py doesn't work, the redirect_authenticated_user is not supported by PasswordResetView.

Comment: see my updated answer(second way).And [read docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options)

Comment: Well, this is not going to work, and I think there is not paragraph in the docs that would prove the opposite.

Comment: I think first way is recommended because according to django docs. **warning** If you enable `redirect_authenticated_user`, other websites will be able to determine if their visitors are authenticated on your site by requesting redirect URLs to image files on your website. To avoid this [social media fingerprinting](https://robinlinus.github.io/socialmedia-leak/) information leakage, host all images and your favicon on a separate domain.